# Locale Date in IE returning NaN

Tags: internet-explorer, date, locale

Here, dt is the date, it can be in any locale format eg: 20.01.1980 or 20/01/1980..... and in this function

```
function formISODate(dt){
if(dt != ""){
    var date = (typeof(dt) == "string") ? dojo.date.stamp.fromISOString(dt) :
                (typeof(dt)=="object") ? new Date(dt[0]):
                        (typeof(dt)=="number") ? new Date(dt): dt;
            //return dojo.date.locale.format(date, {selector: "date"});
            return date;
}
 return dt;
 }
```

when dt[0]= 20.01.1980; 
new Date(dt[0]) is returning NaN.

So, what is the right way to pass the date in correct format

Answer (score 0):

I believe JavaScript is trying to parse your initial array value as a number. (Numbers can only have one decimal separator, therefore your result is not a number (NaN).

Try treating the initial values as strings: `console.warn( new Date( "01/02/08" ) );`

JS will attempt to convert the string to a valid date value.  Also, be aware that the conversion is based, in part, on your locale settings.

The initial value you're using appears to be "DD.MM.YY" format.  If your system is configured for U.S. English, the conversion will expect values to be in the form of "MM/DD/YY".  Date object ssupports additional method for handling such cases. (It may be necessary to parse the initial value into month, day, and year components and then assemble those into the expected format.)

To learn more, see [Date and Time Strings (JavaScript)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx).  Also, these extended features presume you're using IE9 or later and also using a document type that enables standards mode (e.g. `<!DOCTYPE html>`).

Hope this helps...

-- Lance